# Will empty href pass strictest Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, html, href, content-security-policy

Took all hrefs out of anchor elements.  Would like to add empty hrefs back into anchor tags in order that links can be tabbed to (without `tabindex="0"`), and so that a right click will bring up a context menu allowing a user to open a new window or tab.  Anchor links would look like

```
<a href class="some class">.
```

Have searched stack overflow and internet for a day without an answer.  Seems like a question anyone implementing a Content Security Policy would be interested in knowing the answer to.  Afraid I might be reintroducing a security vulnerability by reintroducing the href, in any form, to the Anchor tab.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of right clicking on that link to open it in a new tab? The link doesn't go anywhere useful.

Comment: Without a href most browsers will just render a span, why not just use spans with data- attributes and ditch anchors all together?

Comment: @AdamH — They explained that in the first paragraph of the answer. (To some extent anyway, the reasons they give seem quite pointless for links with blank hrefs)

Comment: @Quentin yeah, that's why I asked about it.

Comment: My HTML markup was deleted in my question.  So I'll try &le;a href class="some class"&gt;